# Can I check is a page present w/ jQuery

Tags: jquery

If I have a URL, can I check if the page is present or not with jQuery? For example if it returns 400 Error, I'll execute one command and if not 400, another command?

Would I use AJAX call for it? Or what's the best way to handle it?

Sorry, did not realise this was important. URL is not on the same domain...

Comment: have you even read the [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) documentation?

Comment: You can only do this if the page you are testing is on the same domain as the page you are on. Otherwise, cross-domain restrictions will cause problems.

Comment: yes, my bad. It is on another domain. @Justin Niessner mentioned done() and fail() -- I'll look into those.

Answer (score 4):

If the page you want to check is on the same server you can use the `success` and `error` callbacks in `$.ajax()` to determine if the page exists:

```
$.ajax('path/to/file.html', {
    error : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('File Not Found');
    },
    success : function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
       alert('File Found');
    }
});
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

And an excerpt from the docs regarding the `error` callback function:

> Note: This handler is not called for cross-domain script and JSONP
>   requests.

**UPDATE**

To do this with PHP:

```
<?php
if (fopen($_GET['url'], "r")) {
    echo "success";
} else {
    echo "error";
}
?>
```

And then in JS you can poll this PHP file:

```
$.get('path/to/script.php', { url : 'http://www.google.com/' }, function (response) {
    if (response == 'success') {
        alert("File Found");
    } else {
        alert("File Not Found");
    }
});
```

Here is a list of accepted protocols for the `fopen()` function in PHP: http://us.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php

Comment: @santa In that case you will need to use a server-side script to check for the existance of the remote webpage. You can poll that script via JavaScript so it's close to the same implementation as far as the JS is concerned. Check my **updated** answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could certainly use [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and then look at the response code once the call completes.

If you don't need that much detail and just need to know if a request succeeds or fails you could use `done()` and `fail()` handlers.

Comment: I don't need more than just knowing if it's there or not. I'll look into these two. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
$.get("index.html")
  .done(function(){ alert("page exists"); })
  .fail(function(){ alert("page does not exist!"); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the documentation for `jQuery.ajax()`:

[jQuery Ajax Doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Note the `statusCode` setting which allows you to pass in callback methods which are to be invoked for various responses. You can use this to set one callback if there's an HTTP 400 and a different callback for any other response.

Answer (score 0):

While you can't make AJAX requests cross-domain for security purposes (see: [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy))

You could call back to your webserver via AJAX, then create the web request server side and return the status code.

Also since all you need is the status code you can make the web request type ["HEAD"](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4) (instead of ["GET"](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.3)) so you only get the header information (which contains the status code)